# HTMLtags in input field

Tags: jquery, html

I have a question about inserting values into an input field from my MYSQL DB.

First I have a form to save data from an inputfield to the database. An extra script filters diacrits `Á`=>`&Aacute;` to html code. So `Állo` will be saved like `&Aacute;llo`

When I insert the data from the DB to a 'div' it shows `Állo`. When I insert the data into a input field it shows `&Aacute;llo`

What am I doing wrong

I use JQUERY to save data to the DB with the $.post method without pagerefresh. I also get the data from the DB with JQUERY $.post method without pagerefresh.

Hope somebody can help.

Comment: Why would you save normal characters as HTML entities? You only need to encode characters that have special meaning in HTML (`<>&` and sometimes `"'`)

Comment: I don't know a better way to be sure that Á will be shown the same on all browsers. I saw that not all browsers show Á good, sometimes they show Á as '?'

Comment: The correct way is to be consistent with character encoding. Choose one (UTF-8 is the best) and stick to it. And remember to tell the browser that you're using it as well.

Comment: @megapool if you set your encodings right, there will be no need for this.

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen. How do I do that? I also use PHP, do I need to tell the page that I'm using UTF8?

Comment: ...I'm not even going to start talking about how badly PHP fails at text (which is, by far, the most important part of the web)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777278/php-best-practice-do-i-save-html-tags-in-db-or-store-the-html-entity-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you really shouldn't save htmlentities to your database. you should instead save `Állo` and use `htmlspecialshars($my_value_from_db);` if its needed (this is php don't know whats runnung on your server, but there are similar functions for perl or other languages). if you can't change the saving process or correct al old entries, you could use `html_entity_decode($bla)` for values that are shown in input-fields (this is php again)

Comment: This did the trick. I looked up for the encoding and I needed to utf8_encode my string I gave back.

Tnx!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting HTML into the div, but setting the DOM value property of the input directly.

An HTML entity is converted to what it represents in HTML, but the value property expects text so doesn't attribute any special meaning to the `&`.

You should be storing the actual data in the database, not an HTML view of it. Conversion to HTML should be handled on the way out of the server side program (in the View if you are using an MVC design pattern).

Comment: Ok, tnx, but when I insert the Á from the DB into the input field my browser shows the '?' or an other symbol and not the Á. I don't want to change my browser settings because viewers of my page must see Á and not the '?'

Answer (score 0):

Have a script that reverses what the encoding script does and call it when you output to the form fields.